# Remote Desktop Connection with Ngrok

Tags: windows-10, port, host, remote-desktop, ngrok

I want connect to my other computer with remote desktop connection but i need a problem.

I did setup ngrok and launched it and tried connect it but it doesn't connect.

This is what i did:

Setup and launched ngrok as:

> ngrok tcp 5555

and i switched my own laptop and launched remote desktop connection and did that:

[image]

But it doesn't connect :(

Note: I allowed Remote Desktop Connection in control panel.

Did i miss something or how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong port number for your remote desktop connection. You have to use default RDP port 3389.
Setup and launched ngrok as:

```
ngrok tcp 3389
```